# Does complex analytic function $f(z)$ imply $f'(z)$ continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis

Just ask a very fundamental question.

I am reading the following textbook:
`Ablowitz and Fokas: Complex Variables, Introduction and Applications, second edition`

On p.83, it says

> analytic only means $f'(z)$ exists, not that it is necessarily continuous

On p.38, it says

> an analytic function has derivatives of all orders in the region of analyticity and that the real and imaginary parts have continuous derivatives of all orders as well

On p.37, Definition 2.1.1 says

> $f(z)$ is said to be analytic at $z_0$ if $f(z)$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

If $f(z)$ has derivatives of all orders, I think $f'(z)$ should be continuous, right? Otherwise $f(z)$ is not differentiable.

So I am confused about the three statements above.

Is there an example that $f(z)$ is analytic in $D$ but $f'(z)$ is not continuous in $D$?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It's a theorem that existence of $f'$ implies existence of all derivatives. Yes, that is indeed surprising if you haven't seen this before. Look it up in the textbook.

Comment: @HansEngler So does it imply $f'$ is continuous?   Thanks!

Comment: @sleevechen A differentiable function is continuous, so yes. What's confusing you here is that we *start* from what looks like a weak definition (just existence of $f'$ which does not *a priori* imply continuity of $f'$) and we *get* a lot out of it.

Comment: The wording in the book is poor. I think the author is trying to get you to think about the fact that, in general, it's possible for a derivative to exist, but not be continuous. For analytic functions, this is not the case. Better wording would be a reference to real differentiable functions, where the author likely is assuming the reader's intuition is coming from.

Comment: @zugzug: The quote on p. 83 is taken out of context here, and I think the actual wording in the book is perfectly clear. (See my comment to Michael Hardy's answer.)

Comment: @sleevechen : In the future, we don't all own the book and have it in front of us. We are answering the question in front of us.

"(note so far in our development, analytic only means f′(z) exists, not that it is necessarily continuous)" is an important quote that clears everything up. I apologize to the authors for criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the statements on pages 83 and 37 contradict each other.

The function $f(z) = |z|^2$ is differentiable only at $z=0.$ I would not call it analytic, nor holomorphic. There is a fastidious distinction that says "holomorphic" means (complex-)differentiable in an *open* set, whereas "analytic" means locally equal to the sum of a convergent power series. But in the context of functions from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C,$ those two can be shown to be the same, and many authors will make no such distinction. But even those who make no such distinction I would expect **not** to consider $z\mapsto |z|^2$ to be $\text{“analytic at $0,$”}$ since there is no open neighborhood of $0$ within which it's differentiable.

Comment: I don't think there's any contradiction. Did you read the actual text? The quote from p. 83 is taken out of context here. In the book, it's a comment about a proof where the assumption is "if $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain", and they point out that in this proof they are assuming that $f'$ is continuous, but there is another proof in an optional section where this isn't assumed, and the full quote is "(note so far in our development, analytic only means $f'(z)$ exists, not that it is necessarily continuous)". Nowhere do they claim that $|z|^2$ is analytic.

Comment: @HansLundmark : I have only the original question above to tell me what is in the book.

Comment: @HansLundmark I knew this. But my question is another quote "an analytic function has derivatives of all orders in the region of analyticity". Does this quote imply $f'$ is continuous?  If not, does it imply an analytic function, which is differentiable, is not continuous?     As it says $f'$ does not have to be continuous but it has derivatives of all orders.

Comment: @sleevechen: Yes, of course it implies that $f'$ is continuous (as already said in Ian's comment to your question). But on p. 83 the fact that $f'$ is continuous hasn't been proved yet, it's not proved until Theorem 2.6.2 on p. 93 (as mentioned in the quote from p. 38 which you also removed from its context: "We shall see, in a later section (2.6.1), that an analytic function has derivatives of all orders" etc.).